# add these values in a list using python "app and a.b.c.d" Output in ["app", "and","a.b.c.d"]

Tags: python

I am having Text to convert in a list

```
"app and a.b.c.d"
```

Output should be

```
["app", "and", "a.b.c.d"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> "app and a.b.c.d".split()
['app', 'and', 'a.b.c.d']
```